# How to show Toast in Windows Phone while app is running?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my `Windows Phone` app, there are two buttons. I want to show some useful `toast` on `click` event of that buttons. I've explored some stuff to show toast but it works only for `background` applications. Is there any simple way to show toast messages while app is running. Any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is,

1. Roll your own, use the tutorial [here](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/02/21/Add-a-persistent-element-to-your-phone-apps.aspx) as a base. Or,
2. [The coding for fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)

**Coding for fun toolkit**

Install the nuget package >  Install-Package Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls

In your xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
       <Button Content="Show Toast" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ShowToast" />
</Grid>
```

In your code:

```
private void ShowToast(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var toast = new ToastPrompt
       {
           Title = "The Title",
           Message = "A message",
           FontSize = 50,
           TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
           ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
       };

       toast.Show();
   }
```

Read more about how you can customize it [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-toast-prompt-in-depth)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use push notifications and want to intercept a Toast Message when your app is in the foreground, you can use something like the below. Note this uses the Coding 4 Fun prompt as mentioned by FunksMaName.

Setup an event handler when you setup your channel (and every time the app starts)

```
 CurrentChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += CurrentChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived;
```

Then to handle the event

```
 void CurrentChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {
               ToastPrompt prompt = new ToastPrompt()
               {
                   TextOrientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
                   Title = e.Collection["wp:Text1"],
                   Message = e.Collection["wp:Text2"],
                   ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(<image URI here>, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
               };
               prompt.Show();
           });
    }
```